# rspec POST api testing on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

my routes.rb

```
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    namespace :api, path: '/' do
      scope '/v1' do
        scope '/things' do
          post '/', to: 'things#create'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

All I want to do now is testing the POST method here in rspec controller testing:

```
it 'should create things on a post request' do
  post 'create',
   { thing: { foo: bar }.to_json
  assert_equal 204, response.status
end
```

I end up getting this:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: post 'create',
>  ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>  No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"api/things"}
> ```

I suppose this has to do with the `api` subdomain constraint so I keep trying to initialise the subdomain in rspec:

```
request.host = 'api.mydevdomain.dev'
```

I also tried to include the whole URL in the post request but no success.

How can I set the subdomain in rspec for my example above? Is this the reason for the error or is there another cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the routes up like this instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api', as: 'api' do
      namespace 'v1' do
        resources :things
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In order to set up a versioned api you should put each controller in a "version module". So your Api::ThingsController should be:

```
# controllers/api/v1/things_controller.rb
class Api::V1::ThingsController
  # ...

  # POST /api/v1/things
  def create
  end
end
```

And then you can test it with:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::ThingsController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "returns http success" do
      post :create, { thing: { foo: bar }, format: :json}
      expect(response).to have_http_status :created
      expect(response.headers['location']).to eq thing_path(Thing.last)
    end
  end
end
```

But if you really want to test the routing layer as well use a [request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) instead. Which is like a feature spec but without the overhead of Capybara.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to manually encode the request parameters in fact doing so may lay to double encoding errors. Just set the format and let RSpec do its thing.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you are getting that result or why your spec is even running at all since it contains a syntax error. But this is tested to work.